# speedtest-cli implementation on Kivy works on PC but not on Android

Tags: python, android, python-3.x, kivy, buildozer

I am trying out a simple speedtest application to learn **Kivy** and **speedtest-cli** (https://pypi.org/project/speedtest-cli/). The speedtest.py code has output successful speed test result on PC but not Android (Buildozer) as shown:

**Screenshot on PC:**
[image: Screenshot on PC]

**Screenshot of Buildozer & Android:**
[image: Screenshot on Android (Buildozer)]
[image: Screenshot on Android (No result)]

The implementation is as simple as a button and importing *speedtest.py* script. The *speedtest.py* has been modified mainly on the outputs. However, buildozer's implementation on my Android phone (Android Version 9) returned "Cannot retrieve speedtest configuration1" found in Line 1870 from shell() in speedtest.py instead and few errors such as IsADirectoryError. Error from:

```
printer('Retrieving speedtest.net configuration...', quiet)
    try:
        speedtest = Speedtest(
            source_address=args.source,
            timeout=args.timeout,
            secure=args.secure
        )
    except (ConfigRetrievalError,) + HTTP_ERRORS:
        printer('Cannot retrieve speedtest configuration1', error=True)
        raise SpeedtestCLIError(get_exception())
```

Below are some code snippets:

**main.py:**

```
import threading, speedtest, global_var as g

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRectangleFlatButton
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivymd.uix.menu import MDDropdownMenu
from kivymd.uix.snackbar import Snackbar
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.core.window import Window

# SSL certificate for HTTPS request
import certifi
import os
os.environ['SSL_CERT_FILE'] = certifi.where()

class SpeedTest_Screen(Screen):
    def getSpeedTest(self):
    self.loading_button.active = True
    self.req_button.opacity = 0
    self.req_button.disabled = 1
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=self.retSpeedTest).start()
    print(f"ret : {g.speed_test_src}, {g.speed_test_host}, {g.speed_test_dl}, {g.speed_test_up}")

def retSpeedTest(self):
    g.speed_test_src, g.speed_test_host, g.speed_test_dl, g.speed_test_up = speedtest.main()
    self.ret_speedtest.text = g.speed_test_src+"\n\n"+g.speed_test_host+"\n\n"+g.speed_test_dl+"\n\n"+g.speed_test_up
    self.loading_button.active = False
    self.req_button.opacity = 1
    self.req_button.disabled = 0
pass

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
    # Theming : https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/themes/theming/index.html
    self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Blue"
    # self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Light"

if __name__ == "__main__":
MainApp().run()
```

**main.kv:**

```
#:kivy 2.0.0
#:include speedtest_screen.kv

Screen:
   # Top Tool Bar
   MDToolbar:
       id: toolbar
       # title: "Main"
       elevation: 10
       anchor_title: "center"
    
       size_hint: 1,.1
       pos_hint: {"top":1}

   NavigationLayout:
    
       # Define screens
       ScreenManager:
        id: screen_manager
        size_hint: 1,1
        poshint: {"top":1,"left":1}
        
        SpeedTest_Screen:
            name: "speedtest_screen"
            id: speedtest_screen
            x: toolbar.height
            size_hint_y: 1.0 - toolbar.height/root.height
```

**speedtest_screen.kv:**

```
#:kivy 2.0.0

<SpeedTest_Screen>:

ret_speedtest: ret_speedtest
req_button: req_button
loading_button: loading_button

FloatLayout:
    BoxLayout:
        MDLabel:
            text: "Client"+"\n\nHost"+"\n\nDownload"+"\n\nUpload"
            halign: "right"
        MDLabel:
            text: ":"+"\n\n:"+"\n\n:"+"\n\n:"
            halign: "center"
        MDLabel:
            id: ret_speedtest
            text: "N/A"+"\n\nN/A"+"\n\nN/A"+"\n\nN/A"
            halign: "left"

    MDFillRoundFlatButton:
        id: req_button
        text: "Run"
        size_hint: .3,.1
        pos_hint: {"top":.15,"center_x":.5}
        on_release: 
            root.getSpeedTest()
            
    MDSpinner:
        id: loading_button
        size_hint: .1,.1
        pos_hint: {"top":.15,"center_x":.5}
        active: False
```

**Buildozer.spec:**

```
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas, ttf, db, txt
requirements = python3,kivy==2.0.0rc1, kivymd, openssl, certifi
android.permissions = INTERNET, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
android.api = 29
android.logcat_filters = *:S python:D
```

**Buildozer Error Log**

```
04-28 21:28:06.803 23393 23604 I python  : ret : N/A, N/A, N/A, N/A
04-28 21:28:06.848 23393 23900 I python  : Retrieving speedtest.net configuration...
04-28 21:28:06.863 23393 23900 I python  :  Cannot retrieve speedtest configuration1
04-28 21:28:06.864 23393 23900 I python  :  Exception in thread Thread-1:
04-28 21:28:06.865 23393 23900 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):
04-28 21:28:06.866 23393 23900 I python  :    File "/home/icdn/speedtest_test/.buildozer/android/app/speedtest_mod.py", line 1807, in shell
04-28 21:28:06.867 23393 23900 I python  :    File "/home/icdn/speedtest_test/.buildozer/android/app/speedtest_mod.py", line 1081, in __init__
04-28 21:28:06.869 23393 23900 I python  :    File "/home/icdn/speedtest_test/.buildozer/android/app/speedtest_mod.py", line 597, in build_opener
04-28 21:28:06.915 23393 23900 I python  :    File "/home/icdn/speedtest_test/.buildozer/android/app/speedtest_mod.py", line 666, in build_user_agent
04-28 21:28:06.916 23393 23900 I python  :    File "/home/icdn/speedtest_test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/platform.py", line 1205, in platform
04-28 21:28:06.917 23393 23900 I python  :    File "/home/icdn/speedtest_test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/platform.py", line 193, in libc_ver
04-28 21:28:06.919 23393 23900 I python  :  IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/data/data/org.test.speedtest/files/app'
04-28 21:28:06.919 23393 23900 I python  :  
04-28 21:28:06.935 23393 23900 I python  :  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
04-28 21:28:06.936 23393 23900 I python  :  
04-28 21:28:06.937 23393 23900 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):
04-28 21:28:06.948 23393 23900 I python  :    File "/home/icdn/speedtest_test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
04-28 21:28:06.972 23393 23900 I python  :    File "/home/icdn/speedtest_test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/speedtest/jnius/__init__.py", line 84, in jnius_thread_hook
04-28 21:28:06.984 23393 23900 I python  :    File "/home/icdn/speedtest_test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/threading.py", line 870, in run
04-28 21:28:06.990 23393 23900 I python  :    File "/home/icdn/speedtest_test/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 29, in retSpeedTest
04-28 21:28:07.007 23393 23900 I python  :    File "/home/icdn/speedtest_test/.buildozer/android/app/speedtest_mod.py", line 1905, in main
04-28 21:28:07.009 23393 23900 I python  :    File "/home/icdn/speedtest_test/.buildozer/android/app/speedtest_mod.py", line 1814, in shell
04-28 21:28:07.012 23393 23900 I python  :  speedtest_mod.SpeedtestCLIError: 
[Errno 21] Is a directory: '/data/data/org.test.speedtest/files/app'
```

Link to Github (including buildozer.spec): https://github.com/johnchen99/Speedtest-Test

Comment: You may need to handle runtime permission requests. See the [documentation](https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/apis/#runtime-permissions).

Comment: Thank you @JohnAnderson for your suggestion, I have added

`request_permissions([Permission.INTERNET, Permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE])`

from android.permissions into the main() as well as updated the buildozer.spec, the app did asked for location permission but nothing regarding to the Internet. Unfortunately, the results are still the same.


https://github.com/johnchen99/Speedtest-Test/blob/master/main.py